# On a locally-compact group $h(x^{-1})$ constant a.e. $\implies h(x)$ constant a.e. (proof of uniqueness of Haar measure)

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to understand the final step in a proof of uniqueness of left Haar measures on locally-compact groups as presented in Knapp's ["Advanced Real Analysis"](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Eaknapp/download/a2-1-realanal-inside.pdf) (pg. 224-225) or [this note](https://home.agh.edu.pl/%7Erudol/Paradoxes/haarintegral.pdf) by Pedersen (pg. 5). Both proofs proceed roughly as follows

> Let $\mu,\lambda$ be left Haar measures on the $\sigma$-compact LCG $G$, wlog assume $\mu\leq\lambda$ (otherwise replace $\lambda$ by $\mu+\lambda$). By Radon-Nikodym there exists $h:G\to[0,\infty)$ with $d\mu=hd\lambda$. For $g$ arbitrary fixed and $f\geq0$ arbitrary by translation-invariance (here $L_gf(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$)
> $$\int f\cdot L_gh\,d\lambda=\int L_{g^{-1}}f\cdot h\,d\lambda=\int L_{g^{-1}}f\,d\mu=\int f\,d\mu=\int f\cdot h\,d\lambda$$
> $\implies L_gh\,d\lambda=h\,d\lambda$ as measures $\implies$ for any $g$ holds $L_gh=h$ $\lambda$-a.e.. It follows that the function $g\mapsto\int|L_gh-h|\,d\lambda(x)$ is zero, so by Tonelli
> $$\iint|L_gh-h|\,d\lambda(g)d\lambda(x)=\iint|L_gh-h|\,d\lambda(x)d\lambda(g)=0,$$
> hence for $\lambda$-almost every choice of $x$ holds
> $$\int|h(g^{-1}x)-h(x)|\,d\lambda(g)=\int|h(g^{-1})-h(x)|\,d\lambda(g)=0.$$
> Fix such an $x_0$, then $h(g^{-1})=h(x_0)$ for $\lambda$-almost every **$g\implies h(x^{-1})$ is constant $\lambda$-a.e. $\implies h(x)$ is constant $\lambda$-a.e..**

I don't understand the highlighted step, how does $h(x^{-1})$ being costant a.e. imply the unmodified $h(x)$ is constant a.e.? Both Knapp and Pedersen gloss over this detail.

> **Knapp**: [...] and $h(g^{-1}x)=h(x)$ for almost every $x\in G$. We can regard $h(g^{-1}x)$ and $h(x)$ as functions of $(g,x)\in G\times G$; for each $g$, they are equal for almost every $x$. By Fubini’s Theorem they are equal for almost every pair $(g, x)$ (with respect to the product measure), and then for almost every $x$ they are equal for almost every $g$. Pick one such $x$, say $x_0$, then it follows that $h(x) = h(x_0)$ for almost every $x$.

> **Pedersen**:  Fubini’s theorem, applied to the product integral and the function $(x,z)\mapsto h(z^{-1}x)-h(x)$, now shows that the function $x\mapsto\int|h(z^{-1}x)-h(x)|dz=\int|h(z^{-1})-h(x)|dz$ equals zero almost everywhere. It follows that $h$ is constant almost everywhere, as desired.

Comment: The inversion map $\iota \colon G \to G$ given by $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism for any topological group, thus since Haar measure is a Borel measure if the function $h \circ \iota$ is constant ae it follows that $h$ must be constant a.e.

Comment: @krm2233 I don't follow, can you please expand your answer?

Comment: Alternatively, go back and change every $g$ to $g^{-1}$.

Comment: @user10354138 doesn't work, we need $g^{-1}$ to get rid of the $x$ in $h(g^{-1}x)$ by **left** translation-invariance in the second-to-last step.

Comment: I mean **every** $g$ to $g^{-1}$, including changing e.g. $L_g$ to $L_{g^{-1}}$ etc. in the whole proof.

Comment: @krm2233 That's not true in this generality. For example, translation is a group homomorphism on $\mathbb R$ and the measure $\frac 1 2(\delta_0+\delta_1)$ is a Borel measure. Yet $1_0+1_1$ is constant $\mu$-a.e. on $\mathbb R$, but if you translate it by $1$, you get a fct. that is $0$ on a set of measure $1/2$ and $1$ on a set of measure $1/2$.

Comment: @user10354138 it doesn't work, precisely for the reason I stated. Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: @user10354138 How do you deal with the fact that $h(gx)$ is a right translation but $d\lambda$ is a left Haar measure? It seems important in what's written that $g \mapsto h(g^{-1}x)$ is the same as $L_x ( h \circ e)$ where $e$ is the inversion map. Trying to view this map as a function of $g^{-1}$ also doesn't help since the pushforward of $\lambda$ by $e$ is a right Haar measure.

Comment: @krm2233, (as noted by MaoWao). $h\circ \iota$ is a.e. constant on $\iota^{-1}(\mathrm{supp}\lambda),$ the support of Haar measure is the whole group and result follows.

Comment: @dsh I'm not sure I'm following this argument, in general if $h\circ \iota$ is $\lambda$-a.e. constant on $\iota^{-1}(S)$, then that means $h$ is $\iota_*\lambda$-a.e. constant on $S$.  Unless you have absolute continuity in measure for $\iota$ (technically for $\iota^{-1}$ but they are the same) with respect  to $\lambda$, then you can't conclude $h$ is $\lambda$-a.e. constant on $S$.  That is the key fact that seems to be missing here, that we don't know a priori that inversion is absolutely continuous in measure.

Comment: @MW Agree. Using that simple argument we only get that: if $h$ is a.e constant for $\lambda$ then $h^\Phi$ is a.e constant for $\lambda_\Phi$ using notation from text (p.221).

On the positive side we do not need $x \mapsto x^{-1}.$ There proved that for almost all $(g, x)\in G\times G$ we have $h(g^{-1}x)=h(x)$ (or by left invariance and Fubini) that $h(gx)=h(x)$).

Absolute continuity of Haar measure wrt homeomorphisms is proved sooner or later, but it is not needed for the question...

Comment: @MW This was suggested by user10354138 earlier in this comment chain. See my last comment for an explanation of how that step is completed and why it doesn't work when replacing $g^{-1}$ with $g$.

Comment: @RhysSteele thanks, I even saw that in the discussion, but didn't fully process what was being said and glossed over it.  I think I understand now.

Comment: @MaoWao you're absolutely right, it is not enough for $\lambda$ to be a Borel measure to conclude $\iota$ preserves null sets, sorry about that. My answer below hopefully shows it is not too hard to deduce that $\iota$ sends the relevant null sets to null sets at least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to fix $x_0$ and use $h(x_0)$ as the constant.  Instead, argue as follows.
Having established that
$$\int|h(g^{-1})-h(x)|\,d\lambda(g)=0\text{,}$$
for a.e. $x$, go back to Tonelli again and conclude
$$\int|h(g^{-1})-h(x)|\,d\lambda(x)\,d\lambda(g)=\int|h(g^{-1})-h(x)|\,d\lambda(g)\,d\lambda(x)=0\text{,}$$
so that for almost every every $g$ we have
$$\int|h(g^{-1})-h(x)|\,d\lambda(x)=0\text{.}$$
Then fix such a $g=g_0$ and observe that $h(g_0^{-1})=h(x)$ for $\lambda$-a.e. $x$.

Comment: I think that works, thanks! Though I'm still wondering how Pedersen did it, seeing as he made no reference to using Tonelli again.

Comment: @HilbertJr. I suspect it might be just an oversight, given that left and right Haar measures have the same nullsets, which is established almost immediately afterwards with the modular function I think, so he may have subconsciously used it a bit too early.

Answer (score 0):

Knapp's argument shows that there is a $\lambda$-null set $N\subset G$ such that if $x_0\in N^c=G\backslash N$ and we set $h_{x_0}(g) := |h(g^{-1}x_0)-h(x_0)|$ then $\text{supp}(h_{x_0}) = L_{x_0}$ where $L_{x_0}$ is a $\lambda$-null set. Let $\iota\colon G\to G$ be given by $\iota(g)=g^{-1}$. Then it is easy to check that $h(x)\neq h(x_0)$ if and only if $x \in \iota(M_{x_0})$ where $M_{x_0}:=x_0^{-1}L_{x_0}$, and by left-invariance $M_{x_0}$ is $\lambda$-null. Thus the following claim implies that $h$ is constant a.e. and so completes the proof of uniqueness:

*Claim:* $\iota(M_{x_0})$ is $\lambda$-null.

*Proof*: Suppose not, so that $\iota(M_{x_0})$ is not $\lambda$-null. Then as $\lambda(N)=0$ we must have  $\iota(M_{x_0})\cap N^c\neq \emptyset$ and so we may pick $x_1 \in\iota(M_{x_0})\cap N^c$. But $x_1 \in N^c$ implies, exactly as for $x_0$, that we must have $h(x)= h(x_1)$ if and only if $x\in \iota(M_{x_1})^c$ where $M_{x_1}$ is $\lambda$-null, and since $x_1 \in \iota(M_{x_0})$, if $x \in \iota(M_{x_1})^c$ then $h(x)=h(x_1)\neq h(x_0)$ and hence $\iota(M_{x_1})^c \subseteq \iota(M_{x_0})$, or equivalently $\iota(M_{x_0})\cup\iota(M_{x_1}) =G$. Applying $\iota$ to this equality  $M_{x_0}\cup M_{x_1} = G$ and hence $\lambda(G) =0$, which is a contradiction since $G$ is open. Thus $\iota(M_{x_0})$ must be null and $h$ is constant almost everywhere as required.